# Grid gallery shows stretch on actual phone, but on on mobil view on PC

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a gallery using grid layout. It worked just fine when I viewed it on chrome - PC and switched to iPhone resolution. But when I open the website on actual iPhone it shows stretched. I tried using chrome on my iphone instead of safari but its still the same. It works on other phones just fine. Can not figure out the issue.
My code:

```
.imagesGrid__wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.image__gallery {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "img-7 img-2 img-3 img-3" "img-7 img-1 img-3 img-3";
    gap: 1.5rem;
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        position: relative;
    }
}

.img1 {
    grid-area: img-1;
}

.img2 {
    grid-area: img-2;
}

.img3 {
    grid-area: img-3;
}

.img4 {
    grid-area: img-4;
}

.img5 {
    grid-area: img-5;
}

.img6 {
    grid-area: img-6;
}

.img7 {
    grid-area: img-7;
}

.img8 {
    grid-area: img-8;
}


@media (max-width: 840px) {
    .image__gallery {
        gap: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
const ImagesGrid = () => {
  return (
    <div className="imagesGrid__wrapper">
      <div className="image__gallery">
        <img src={img1} alt={img1} className="img1" />
        <img src={img2} alt={img2} className="img2" />
        <img src={img3} alt={img3} className="img3" />
        <img src={img7} alt={img7} className="img7" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImagesGrid;
```

Images:

[image: on pc mobile view:]

[image: on actual phone]

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: try setting fixed height for grid row. eg: `grid-template-rows: 250px`

Comment: @cloned just updated with HTML

Comment: @user3733831 thank you i will try, but I donst understand why it only does that on iphones safari & chrome

Comment: btw it doesn't matter which browser you use on iphone / ipad, they all have the same render engine. So it either works on all browsers or none on these devices.